# When do I use what weapon?

Tags: meteor-blitz

I've come to understand that in Meteor Blitz certain weapons work better against some kinds of debris; what weapons are best for what kind of enemies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ice Bullets can destroy lava meteors, the flamethrower damages ice rocks more than just normal lasers. Gravity Guns are epic, because you can suck in the enemies and meteors. But seriously, I recommend you using the gravity Gun with any enemy. I hope I answered your question!

Comment: I think it answered your question then!