# What weapon to upgrade first?

Tags: meteor-blitz

Related to my previous question, [When do I use what weapon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48091/when-do-i-use-what-weapon) What is the upgrade priority ladder for maximum points and speed?